# How to update dynamic input fields in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

This is the code for storing an array only. What I want now is to update each field or can add new rows but I don't know how.

```
        foreach ($request->requirements as $key => $requirements) {
        $req = new FormReq();
        $req->requirements = $requirements['title'];
        $req->form_id = $id;
        $req->save();
    }
```

My blade file

```
@foreach ($requirements as $reqs)
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="requirements[0][title]"
            placeholder="Enter requirements" class="form-control"
            value="{{ $reqs->requirements }}" />
        </td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove-tr">Remove</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: you can use the update function and pass an array of fields. `$req->update([]); `You will need to retrieve it from database first, like : `FormReq::find(17)` or `FormReq::where('id', 17)->first()`. You can use the form_id field if you need instead of id.

Comment: better if you will code the answer

Comment: @SharmaeReyes can you please elaborate the question a bit more? When do you want to update the entries or add new ones.

Comment: Both, can add and update the entry at the same time

Comment: You can pass the ids of the requirements as hidden variables from the form and update them accordingly:
`<div type='hidden' value='{{ $reqs->id }}' name='id'>`
For adding new entries you can just pass the complete array again to controller and add the additional entries or you can use jquery (easier and efficient way) 
[link](https://www.positronx.io/laravel-dynamically-add-or-remove-multiple-input-fields-with-jquery/)

Comment: If you need to add and update at the same time, then use the updateOrCreate method. And you will need to handle deletion too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add an input hidden in your existing items. Adapt the name of the input if this doesn't work

```
<input type="hidden" name="requirements[][id]" value="{{ $reqs->id }}" />
```

Then check for the presence of the id in your method

```
foreach ($request->requirements as $key => $requirements) {

    // Update
    if (isset($requirements['id']) && $requirements['id']) {
        $req = FormReq::find($requirements['id']);
        $req->requirements = $requirements['title'];
    // Create
    } else {
        $req = new FormReq();
        $req->requirements = $requirements['title'];
        $req->form_id = $id;
    }
    $req->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit to **Yannick's** answer I was able to handle the create and update in **Edit** page, but I added some codes in blade in order for this to work.

I added this code to the script as well

```
<input type="hidden" name="requirements['+ i +'][id]" value="" />
```

```js
var i = 0;
$("#add-btn").click(function() {
  ++i;
  $("#dynamicAddRemove").append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="requirements[' + i +
    '][title]" placeholder="Enter requirement" class="form-control" />  <input type="hidden" name="requirements[' +
    i +
    '][id]" value="" /> </td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr">Remove</button></td></tr>'
  );
});
$(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function() {
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
//handle deletion for existing field
$('.deleteReq').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var req_id = $(this).val();
  $('#req_id').val(req_id)
  $('#deleteModal').modal('show');

});
```

I added **key** to create unique fields

```html
@foreach ($requirements as $key => $reqs)
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="requirements[{{ $key }}][title]" placeholder="Enter requirement" class="form-control" value="{{ $reqs->requirements }}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="requirements[{{ $key }}][id]" value="{{ $reqs->id }}" />
  </td>
  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr deleteReq" value="{{ $reqs->id }}">Remove</button>
  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```